# How do I create a landing page that can go to page--front?

Tags: redirection

I have two pages, the intro page (page--intro.tpl.php) and the front page (page--front.tpl.php). When you type worldovercomers.church, the front page loads.

How can I set it so when the user visits the website the intro page loads instead (worldovercomers.church/intro)?

I also want to include a link that when clicked goes to the main site (page--front). How can this be achieved?

Please note that I'm a Drupal novice.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module.

It has a "pages" feature that allows you to create pages from pre-existing layout templates that are included, or you can create and import your own layouts from .tpl files. Then you can dynamically add content to them (it stores the settings in the database, but you can use the Features module to store them in code).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've tried doing this but I'm editing a theme via pantheon and filezilla. Sadly I don't have direct access to the drupal website.

Comment: Any tips on how to do this without using modules?